# ZF: SubForms and array notation

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've got a Zend_Form object, and I've added a subForm.  What I expected was that if I invoke the render method of the Zend_Form object, it would render its elements as well as the subform's, and the subform's elements' names would be in array notation with the subform title as the array name, and its elements' names as the keys.  However, it's not giving me an array notation for the subform elements.  I only get it if I invoke setIsArray(TRUE) on the subform.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Is your subform of type Zend_Form or Zend_Form_SubForm?  The latter has its isArray property set to true by default.

Comment: @Zach, the subform is of type Zend_Form, but if I add a form using Zend_Form::addSubForm($form), shouldn't the subform get rendered in array notation?

Comment: I think that's just how it works.  The documentation does say "By default, sub forms render using the array notation", but what it probably really means is "By default, Zend_Form_SubForm forms render using the array notation".  Otherwise, the addSubForm method would call setIsArray on the subform, which it doesn't.